# Non-exhaustive patterns in function?

Tags: haskell

I have an error in this code:

```
ordena :: (Ord a) => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
ordena (x,y,z)
  | x > y     =  ordena (y,x,z)
  | x > z     =  ordena (z,y,x)
  | y > z     =  ordena (x,z,y)
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I trust you only got a warning. Can you post the entire error please? Also, what is your function supposed to be doing?

Comment: *** Exception: Practica1.hs:(49,1)-(52,33): Non-exhaustive patterns in function ordena. It takes 3 numbers and order.

Comment: You have an unhandled case... For example, what if x,y and z are all the same? You have to define these cases. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards for an example

Comment: Okay, just solved this problem. Thank u dude.

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling all of the possible cases:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let ordena :: (Ord a) => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
Prelude|     ordena (x,y,z) | x > y     =  ordena (y,x,z)
Prelude|                    | x > z     =  ordena (z,y,x)
Prelude|                    | y > z     =  ordena (x,z,y)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> 
Prelude> ordena 0 0 0

<interactive>:22:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer -> t’
                with actual type ‘(a0, a0, a0)’
    Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:22:1)
    The function ‘ordena’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘(a0, a0, a0) -> (a0, a0, a0)’ has only one
    In the expression: ordena 0 0 0
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = ordena 0 0 0
```

You need to add at least catch-all case to the pattern match:

```
ordena :: (Ord a) => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
ordena (x,y,z) | x > y     =  ordena (y,x,z)
               | x > z     =  ordena (z,y,x)
               | y > z     =  ordena (x,z,y)
               | otherwise =  ...
```

Alternatively, you might want to split the `otherwise` case into 2 or more more specific cases, but I can't tell you what those are because I don't know what `ordena` is supposed to stand for.

---

In general though, you really should include the error message in the question. Right now, we can only guess that it's a runtime error and not a compile error, but sometimes that's not at all obvious, but even when it is, you should include the error.